# Looking for succinct way of describing the act of solidifying an idea into reality

Tags: single-word-requests, popular-refrains, synonyms

Looking for a succinct way of describing the act of solidifying an idea into reality. "Building [idea] out" seems too generic but I'm trying to avoid a long winded, step by step explanation of the process.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You tend to *realise* things like ambitions. The process of converting an *idea* into something that actually exists (as a physical object, a clearly-defined procedure, or some such) is usually called ***implementing*** the idea (putting it into practice, as opposed to mere theory).

Comment: Can you provide a sample sentence with a blank where that word would go?

Comment: Providing the sample sentence is important.  Your question may be closed if you do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **reify**. See [definition by dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reify)

> to convert into or regard as a concrete thing.

For example, *reify a concept*.

See Merriam Webster's *did you know* section [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reify)

Answer (score 3):

***[Realise](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/realise):***

> - to make real; give reality to (a hope, fear, plan, etc.).

- To realise an idea.

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 1):

[fruition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fruition) (as in, bring/brought to fruition)

> the state of being real or complete

*These were dreams of long standing that had finally come to fruition … —Nicholas Fraser, Harper's, September 1996*

*Truth is a weapon so powerful that the slowness of its fruition matters little in the end. —Edith Hamilton, New Yorker, 12 Sept. 1994*

*The ground thaws, the sap flows, then comes the leaf, the bud, the full flowering of national and individual entitlements, an unstoppable surge toward the glorious fruition promised by the idea of independence. —Janette Turner Hospital, New York Times Book Review, 30 Dec. 1990*